# Output data to web browser in ruby-on-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In PHP I could echo data to the web browser to debug.

eg. echo print_r($array)

How do I do that in RoR? I tried with puts with no luck.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using:

```
 <%= debug(@array) %>
```

in the template file or use something like:

```
 logger.info @array.inspect
```

in your controller. This will print the contents of array into the server development log.